# Did I integrate this correctly?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

The question was:
$$\int 2x^2 (x^3-4)^6\ dx$$

My answer was $\dfrac{(x^3-4)^7}{7} + C$.

If my answer is wrong please show me the correct method. The textbook doesn't have answers so I turn to my trusty stackexchange users.

Comment: It might be useful to you to check out [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on mathjax to make your questions look nice and pretty :D

Comment: Why are you asking this? Can't you simply differentiate the supposed result and check whehter you get the functions that was integrated??

Comment: @user151764, you have done write but not taken constant $2/21$

Comment: @DonAntonio only if you know the FTC :D

Comment: There are some online calculators to help finding integrals, limits,  series, or derivatives.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything at all, @DanZimm ? This is indefinite integration = anti-differentiation.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah fair enough

Comment: You all had good answers I didn't want to have to choose one answer but it's not possible to choose more than one. Thanks guys for all the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Letting $$u = x^3 - 4 \implies du = 3x^2\,dx \iff \frac{du}{3} = x^2\,dx \iff \dfrac 23\,du = 2x^2$$

$$\int 2x^2(x^3 - 4)^6 \,dx = \int (\underbrace{x^3 - 4}_{\large u})^6(\underbrace{2x^2\,dx}_{\large \frac 23 \,du}) = \int u^6 \left(\frac 23 du\right) = \dfrac 23\int u^6\,du$$

So you'll need to multiply your result by $\dfrac 23$: $$\dfrac 23\cdot  \frac{u^{7}}{7} + c = \dfrac 2{21}(x^3 - 4)^7 + c$$

Comment: Okay thank you I see what I did wrong. I forgot to multiply by 2/3 to make du/dx equal 2x^2.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Let $u=x^3-4\;\Rightarrow\;du=3x^2\ dx$, then
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\int 2x^2(x^3-4)^6\ dx&=\int 2\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{x^2}}}u^6\cdot\frac{du}{3\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{x^2}}}}\\
&=\frac23\int u^6\ du\\
&=\frac23\cdot\frac17u^7+C\\
&=\frac2{21}(x^3-4)^7+C.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks mate really helpful!

Comment: @user151764 You're welcome. $\ddot\smile$